# OperationalError:(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, streamlit

The problem I am facing is:

> OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8

While using streamlit, program has shows me this error, while it has worked quite fine for month but now it shows me every time this error as there is no error in query as well.

As I am using sqlachemy to connect to the database, I am connecting to the database using sqlalchemy in streamlit python, it was running quite fine, but now it shows me the above error, as there is no error in query.

Comment: Error says MySQL but you have tagged SQL Server which is a completely different product, please correct your tags.

Comment: If you're trying to use MySQL libraries to connect to SQL Server, there's your problem.